# Wrong "uid" when searching with imaplib

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I am experiencing a strange problem while developing my python application.

The application is supposed to parse a mail inbox for the unread messages, get a specific ones, process the body and store it into a database.

Everything seem to be working fine for my first 7 mails from my domain, but with the last one and the 4 @gmails, the results don't match with the expected, the mails stored into the database aren't the correct ones, in fact, they are exactly the 4th mail after the correct one.

I am showing the code that I developed, don't be too hard with me, I am kinda new coding:

**main**.py

```
from src_pckg import reader

reader.read("***@m***p.com", "***", "imap.***.com", 993, "noreply@s***d.com")
```

reader.py

```
def read(username, password, host, port, sender_of_interest):
    #Con details
    imap_con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host, port)
    imap_con.login(username, password)
    imap_con.select("INBOX")

    #Print all unread messages from a certain sender
    status, response = imap_con.search(None, 'UNSEEN', '(FROM "%s")' % (sender_of_interest))
    unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()
    print(len(unread_msg_nums))
    for e_id in unread_msg_nums:
        status, data = imap_con.uid('fetch', e_id, '(RFC822)')
        msg = data[0][1].decode(encoding='UTF-8')

        if re.search("has given you a gift subscription", msg):

            #Process the mail

    return True
```